# n power n print 'Hello World' without calculating the value

Tags: python, loops, recursion, exponent

I want to print Hello World `n**n` times without calculating the value of `n**n` in python.

eg,

if n is 2, it should print `'Hello World'` 4 times.

if n is 3 it should print `'Hello World'` 27 times and so on.

I am allowed to use loops and recursion but now allowed to use any inbuilt function or calculate the value of n **n and print that many times.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Range is allowed but your answer will give `n**2`  always. I want `n**n`

Comment: This is basically impossible (in Python 3), because `print` is also a built-in function.

Comment: This is not "do my homework" site... What have you tried?

Comment: This is not my homework. This is asked in an interview and i tried many things. I am able to reach square but not `n**n`. By inbuilt function it meant functions to calculate exponent like `**` or math.power etc.

Comment: Write an `ntimes` higher-order function that applies its argument to its argument's argument n times in a row. Call `ntimes` on itself with `n`, then call the result on `partial(print, 'Hello World')`.

Comment: @abarnert I am still not clear. can you please give it a try?

Comment: @Graipher Nope. Well, yes, but it's the same as `n` nested for loops instead of two. That's how we get `n**n` instead of `n**2`. And that should give you a nice clue on how to write this pythonically with `itertools`, or how to write a simple recursive version, but I wanted to write it differently, so… see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First:

```
def compose(f, g):
    def wrapper(x):
        return f(g(x))
    wrapper.__name__ = f'compose({f.__name__}, {g.__name__})'
    return wrapper

def ntimes(n):
    def wrap(func):
        if n == 1: return func
        return compose(func, ntimes(n-1)(func))
    return wrap
```

That should be obvious, right? `ntimes(3)` is a function that composes any function with itself 3 times, so `ntimes(3)(func)(x)` is `func(func(func(x)))`.

And now, we just need to call `ntimes` on `ntimes` with the same `n` at both levels. I could write an `nntimes` function that does that the same way `ntimes` did, but for variety, let's make it flatter:

```
def nntimes(n, func, arg):
    f = ntimes(n)
    return f(f)(func)(arg)
```

So `nntimes(n, func, arg)` calls `ntimes(n)` on `ntimes(n)`, which gives you a function that composes its argument `n**n` times, and then calls that function on `arg`.

And now we just need a function to pass in. `print` doesn't quite work, because it returns `None`, so you can't compose it with itself. So:

```
def printret(x):
    print(x, end=' ')
    return x
```

And now we just call it:

```
>>> nntimes(2, printret, 'Hi')
hi hi hi hi
>>> nntimes(3, printret, 'Hi')
hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi
```

---

If you still can't understand what's happening, maybe this will help. Let's do something a bit simpler than the general `nntimes` and just hardcode three, and then print out the composition:

```
>>> thrice = ntimes(3)
>>> print(thrice(thrice)(printret).__name__)
compose(compose(compose(printret, compose(printret, printret)), compose(compose(printret, compose(printret, printret)), compose(printret, compose(printret, printret)))), compose(compose(compose(printret, compose(printret, printret)), compose(compose(printret, compose(printret, printret)), compose(printret, compose(printret, printret)))), compose(compose(printret, compose(printret, printret)), compose(compose(printret, compose(printret, printret)), compose(printret, compose(printret, printret))))))
```

All those parentheses! It's like I've died and gone to Lisp!

---

If you read up on [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals), you'll see that I've sort of cheated here. Write up the trivial functions to Church-encode a number and to exponentiate two Church numerals, then compare it to what my code does. So, have I really avoided calculating the value of `n**n`?

---

Of course you can do this a whole lot more simply with a simple flat recursion and no higher-order functions, or with `itertools` (well, you're not allowed to use builtins, but everything in itertools comes with source and/or or a "roughly equivalent" function in the docs, so you can just copy that). But what's the fun in that? After all, if you actually wanted a Pythonic, or simple, or efficient version, you'd just loop over `range(n**n)`. I assume the point of this interview question is to force you to think outside the Pythonic box.

Comment: It works great. Thank you. I am still a bit confused and trying to understand it step by step.

Comment: @binu.py Great! Try working it through with 1, then 2, before tackling 3. (Don't try 0, because I forgot to handle that…) Maybe try `thrice(twice)` and `twice(thrice)`, too. Also, think about higher-order functions you _do_ understand, like `map` or `functools.partial`, and work through how they work.

Comment: Sure. Thanks @abarnert i understood it now.

Comment: Rereading this the next day, with more coffee in my bloodstream… why didn't I write this up in terms of encoding the ints in Church numerals? That would allow a useful explanatory link, while at the same time allowing me to make the code even more ridiculous for Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def new(number,loop):
...     if loop == 1:
...         return number
...     else:
...         return number * new(number,loop-1)
... 
>>> a = new(3,3)
>>> print a
27
>>> print "Hello "*a
Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
```

> > > 

Comment: I have already tried this. But i am not allowed to calculate the value of n**n just need to print

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun and to give an instructive answer you could do it this way with a very simple recursive function without calculating `n**n`:

```
def fun(n, level):
    if (level == n):
        print('Hello World')
        return 
    for i in range (n):
        fun(n, level+1)
```

And if you try

```
fun(2,0)
```

you get

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

the same works for `fun(3,0)`... Hope that helps. Is a rather trivial solution. @abarnert wonderful solution!

Best, Umberto